# Entity framework linq inner join return object if condition is true

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

```
public UserMaster Login(UserMaster userMaster, string otp)
    {

        return (from um in _context.UserMasters.Where(u => u.UserName == userMaster.UserName && u.Password == userMaster.Password && u.IsDisplay == true && u.IsActive == true)
                join pin in _context.UserPins.Where(p => p.Pin == otp) on um.UserId equals pin.UserId
                select new { um }).SingleOrDefault();
   }
```

I am trying to return a object of User if the Condition are met, i.e if the user has correct pass and username as well as correct otp from a different table. I only need/require to return the User Master Obj.

Giving following error

[image]

Comment: this should work, whats the issue?

Comment: Conversion Error. See the Image link I just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public UserMaster Login(UserMaster userMaster, string otp)
{
       return (from um in _context.UserMasters.Where(u => u.UserName == userMaster.UserName && u.Password == userMaster.Password && u.IsDisplay == true && u.IsActive == true)
              join pin in _context.UserPins.Where(p => p.Pin == otp) on um.UserId equals pin.UserId
              select um).FirstOrDefault();
}
```